# How to copy files/folders from Windows shared location into docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

For copying files/folders from host to container or vice versa I can see docker commands like -

```
docker cp foo.txt mycontainer:/foo.txt
docker cp mycontainer:/foo.txt foo.txt
```

But I've a shared folder from remote location, which I need to copy inside of docker container.

i.e. my pipeline runs on a host A(could be Windows/Linux), shared folder is on remote host B(which is going to be always Windows machine) and need to copy that folder from host B to container running on host A

Is there any docker command to achieve this?

In our case, host A could be Windows or Linux machine hence I'll have to handle it differently hence looking for some docker command irrespective of OS.

Answer (score 0):

Shared folder is located on remote host B using the `SMB protocol`. As  I know, docker does not support any direct command to copy files via SMB protocol to your container.

In your case, let everything work smoothly. You will need to create one more container with the task of running `samba-client`. Then you can get the file from host B and save it to host A with a command like this:

```
smbget -R smb://hostB/directory
```

Then you can copy the files from host A into the container as usual.